# Keep ultragrid selection after the timer refresh

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

I have an ultragrid in my vb.net program and a timer. Each time my timer ticks it resets any selected row i have clicked. So i want on each tick to save the index of the row and reload it after the tick. The thing is that i also have groups in my grid. So i might have 2 groups and on each group i have maybe 3 rows and 5 on the other. So i need to know how can i select the group and the row inside that group to save it and reload it after the tick. I know i select the row with ultragrid.activeRow etc.

here is my groups

```
Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

Timer1.Enabled = True
UltraGrid1.DataSource = Nothing
Generic.openOrders(dt)
UltraGrid1.DataSource = dt
Dim band As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand = UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0)
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.ViewStyleBand = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ViewStyleBand.OutlookGroupBy

band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERDATE"), False, True)
band.SortedColumns.Add(band.Columns("ORDERTIME"), False, True)
band.Columns("USERNAME").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect
band.Columns("QUANTITY").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect
band.Columns("ORDERLIST").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect
band.Columns("LOCATION").CellClickAction = CellClickAction.RowSelect

band.Columns("PAID").Hidden = True
band.Columns("PROCESSING").Hidden = True
band.Columns("COMPLETED").Hidden = True
band.Columns("ITEMTIME").Hidden = True
band.Columns("ITEMPRICE").Hidden = True
band.Columns("ORDERPRICE").Hidden = True
band.Columns("READYORDER").Hidden = True
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowColSizing = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnAutoSizeMode.VisibleRows
UltraGrid1.Rows.ExpandAll(True)
```

My output is something like this:

```
 ORDERDATE:
      ORDERTIME:
      ORDER1 ITEM1
      ORDER1 ITEM2
      ORDER1 ITEM3

      ORDERTIME:
      ORDER2 ITEM1
      ORDER2 ITEM2
 ORDERDATE:
      ORDERTIME:
      ORDER3 ITEM1
      ORDER3 ITEM2
      ORDER3 ITEM3
      ORDER3 ITEM4
```

I managed to get the index of ORDERDATE, ORDERTIME AND ORDER with this code:

```
 If UltraGrid1.Selected.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim rowSelected As UltraGridRow
            For Each rowSelected In UltraGrid1.Selected.Rows
                rowIndex = rowSelected.Index
                itemTimeIndex = rowSelected.ParentCollection.ParentRow.Index
                orderTimeIndex = rowSelected.ParentCollection.ParentRow.ParentCollection.ParentRow.Index

            Next
        End If
```

Now how can i set them back to the new ultragrid?

Comment: It is not really clear what you do in the tick event. Could you poste the relevant code?

Comment: the code is kinda big so ill mess you up. Basically i read orders from a database when the form loads. And on each tick i check if there are new orders so the ultragrid is reloaded from scratch again. So basically i rewrite the ultragrid. And i want to save the selected line which is inside a group and reload it with the new grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the Grid is used to do the grouping and the data that the grid is bound to is flat, you can use ultraGrid1.Rows.GetRowWithListIndex passing in the index of the row in the source list to get the row that you need to activate.

As long as your rows have an ID, you could store that ID and find the same row in the new list and then use the GetRowWithListIndex method to get the new row in the grid.  For the related GroupByRow, there is a ParentRow property exposed by the UltraGridRow that you could use.

Comment: thank you m8. i didnt try it yet. seems like a reasonable answer to me. Ill try it as soon as i can and see what ill find. thanks again for your reply

Comment: Hey m8. happy new year. I managed to get the indexes of all 3, but now am struggling of how to set them on my new grid. any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to call ultraGrid1.Rows.GetRowWithListIndex to get the UltraGridRow that corresponds to the index that you have?

Comment: hey thank you for the reply again. I managed to fix it. I dont have the solution now with me, but i did something totally different. I changed something in my database and added some nested for's by calling their childs and it works. thank you again